# How to create a Spark DataSet when the transformation is not 1:1, but 1:many

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm writing a structured streaming Spark application where I'm reading from a Kafka queue and processing the messages received. The end result I want is a `DataSet[MyMessage]` (where `MyMessage` is a custom object) which I want to queue to another Kafka topic. The thing is, each input message from the consumer Kafka queue can yield multiple `MyMessage` objects, so the transformation is not 1:1, 1:Many.

So I'm doing

```
val messagesDataSet: DataSet[List[MyMessage]] = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
      .option("subscribe", "topic1")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .option("startingOffsets", "offset1")
      .load()
      .select($"value")
      .mapPartitions{r => createMessages(r)}

val createMessages(row: Iterator[Row]): List[MyMessage] = {
   // ...
}
```

Obviously, `messagesDataSet` is a `DataSet[List[MyMessage]]`. Is there a way I can get just a `DataSet[MyMessage]`?

Or is there a way to take a `DataSet[List[MyMessage]]` and then write each `MyMessage` object to another Kafka topic? (That’s my end goal after all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
messagesDataSet.flatMap(identity)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple values using mapPartitions (so it works similarly like flatMap), but you have to return Iterator:

```
  def createMessages(row: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[MyMessage] = {
    row.map(/*...*/) //you need too return iterator here
  }
```